Mounting a NEMA 14-50 inside a kitchen cabinet?
I am replacing my existing gas oven with an induction range and need to run a new circuit for the appliance. The range fits between two small (less than 2'-wide) cabinets, and for a number of reasons, and I'm hoping to take advantage of this to save space behind the range.
Is installing a NEMA 14-50 in a kitchen cabinet a code violation? I don't see any issues with this practice in the NEC, but I am not an expert.
My current plan is to

run THHN in EMT from the basement up through the base of one of these cabinets
have the EMT terminate in a 2-gang electrical box that is surface mounted to the back wall of one of the cabinets
create a small "door" in the side wall of the cabinet to allow the range's plug to pass through and plug into a NEMA 14-50 outlet in the electrical box.

Assuming the EMT and electrical box are affixed to the wall (through the rear wall of the cabinet) and the rest of the circuit is code compliant, are there any issues with this approach?

A slide-in range normally has some void space near the floor to allow room for either wall- or floor-mounted outlet, plug, and power cord, while still sliding the range "all the way in" up to the wall. Are we to assume that your new range does not have space at its rear for these things?

Model # of new appliance?

Is mounting the junction box flush in the cabinet side not an option, for that matter?

I'm with @GregHill—is there any reason not to just put the box/outlet at the base of the wall behind the range?  You can see the cavity the manufacturer leaves for such an outlet in the back in aaaaa's answer, below.

@GregHill: Yeah for the sake of argument, I would assume there is no space behind the range (or just enough for the range cord). The range is against a solid exterior brick wall (old 1880s construction). The gas range I'm replacing is connected to an outlet whose box is embedded into the bricks and a cable run through a chase in the bricks to the basement (which was subsequently filled in with plaster AFAICT).

I would love to stick the new electrical box into that exterior wall, but I have concerns after measuring that this would require chiseling too deep into the bricks.

@ThreePhaseEel: Flush mounting to the side of the cabinet is a good idea, but I don't think there is enough space for it. The range is very close to as wide as the cavity between the cabinets, so having the outlet/plug on the side of the range isn't really an option. Fitting a plug sideways behind the range would require pulling the range far enough out from the cabinets that it would look strange in the room. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

@dan installing outlet on the floor? with a GFCI breaker of course

Summary: you are solving wrong problem. Outlet usually is placed behind the range close to the floor. From Samsung manual:


Is installing a NEMA 14-50 in a kitchen cabinet a code violation? I don't see any issues with this practice in the NEC, but I am not an expert.

Per code all junction boxes (including outlets) need to be accessible without tools. So there should be no problem there. People often put outlet for overhead microwave oven in the cabinet above

Thanks for your answer! It's good to know that this wouldn't be a code violation. Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be enough space behind the range for a NEMA 14-50 plug, receptacle, and electrical box (even taking advantage of the recessed area in the back of the range) unless the box is embedded into the wall, and I don't think embedding into the wall is going to be an option.

@Dan many ranges also support hardwiring...

@ThreePhaseEel yeah i think running wire directly to the stove is the answer. Potentially through the floorboards is OP is worried about having the stove stick out by romex thickness
